# Clarity Labeling Class Instances for Reference

Tags: c#, class, closures, multiple-instances, labeling

So I am still fairly new to C# in practice anyhow.. I've spent some time learning *about* it, but actually using it in practice.. meh. So here's **the over all goal**:

I need to build multiple instances of "Example" and each one should contain its own individual list, which keeps track of multiple instances of another class called Inputs.. and be able to later reference them. I was hoping for a way to more or less label each instance so I can call on individual instances by a particular label.

**My predicament**: My class "Example" will be instantiated multiple times, and each instance needs to also instantiate the other class "Input" multiple times, based on the number indicated by the "_numInputs" var. I'll have the "Example" class check the "_numInputs" every so often to add or remove "Inputs" from the "inputs" list. How can I keep track of individual instances of a class? Specifically to remove particular instances if necessary.

**note**: I've looked into closure and from my understanding, closure is primarily focused towards "labeling" unique "types" to methods/functions... but not instances of a class.. if I'm wrong, could you provide a simple example of how I might label each instance of the class such that I might be able to reference it later directly without affecting other instances of the same class?

```
public class Example
{
    public List<Input> inputs = new List<Input>();
    public Example(int numInputs = 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _numInputs; i++)
        {
            inputs.Add(new Input());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the edits kinda change a lot here; can you possibly reiterate what the fundamental question is here? is there still something that needs answering? if so: what? if it is "provide a simple example of how I might label each instance of the class such that I might be able to reference it later directly without affecting other instances of the same class" - then the answer is simply: keep a reference to the instance you care about in each context

Comment: @MarcGravell Yeah, that's the question I'm aiming towards, but I really need a dynamic way to store references.. when I say I'm going to be instantiating multiple instances, I don't just mean like 3 or 4, I mean... I literally have no idea, it'll be up to some logic to determine how many "Inputs" every instance of "Example" actually has, and may later need to remove said "Inputs" based on conditions.

Comment: what you're essentially asking, then, is "where should I store references to objects"; the only good answer to that is: "where you need them". It is hard to be more specific without *very* detailed context about the specific scenario. In particular, be extremely cautious of storing any references via a `static` field (a `static` list or dictionary, for example) - that might sound convenient, but you have essentially created a memory leak: the static field now prevents garbage collection from working at all (for those objects)

Comment: @MarcGravell Hmm... I see.. I'll close off this Question, you've given me some interesting new things to think about. Thank you! +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, static fields are global to the app-domain. So... don't make it static? It actually sounds like it should be part of the constructor, perhaps with a default of 1 - so:

```
private Input[] _inputs;
public Node(int numInputs = 1) {
    _inputs = new Input[numInputs];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < _inputs.Length ; i++) {
        _inputs[i] = new Input();
    }
}
```

Note that since the constructor is the only time you use this number, there's no point storing it per instance. You could of course expose it to the outside world via something like:

```
public int InputCount => _inputs.Length;
```

Note this only works if the number of "inputs" is fixed at instantiation. If it isn't, then frankly: use a list:

```
private List<Input> _inputs = new List<Input>();
public Node() {} // not strictly needed unless there is another constructor somewhere
```

---

Edit based on comment feedback if the issue is the field initialzer order:

```
private int _numInputs;
private Input[] _inputs;

public Example() {
    _numInputs = 1;
    _inputs = new Input[_numInputs];
    for(int i = 0; i < _inputs.Length; i++) {
        _inputs[i] = new Input();
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot make it non-static. Lol I wouldn't have mentioned it if I could. I get error "CS0236 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" but, I also figured since I'll be adding inputs, I'd use a list instead of an array, so i'll edit that part out. Anyhow, the idea of using the number in the constructor is good as it will need the default value... but it won't be the only time I use the number. I'll update my post gimme a moment.

Comment: @DDeathlonger " A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property" - if *that* is the problem: then just move it into the .ctor - I'll add an example; "but it won't be the only time I use the number. " - once again - if `_numInputs` is always going to equal `_inputs.Length`, there's no point storing it - just use `_inputs.Length;`

Comment: also: `such that I might be able to reference it later directly without affecting other instances of the same class?` a static method called from the outside will affect NO instance of the class. static as you said is globally available. it will not influence any instance unless the instance is calling the method and using the return value. to do what you want you should create an instance of Example using @MarcGravell constructor. And call the fields/method on that very instance.

Comment: @Drag0nvil when you are talking about methods, are you meaning the "constructor" method which is specific to each instance of the class?

Comment: Because I'm saying that I need to later reference specific instances of the class as a whole, not just a method. I.E. All the defining properties and fields within the scope of an individual instance of a class.. again, not just a method.

Comment: I'm sorry I might have missread. To me it sounded like you were wondering or the static method could be called in a way. so it would change the data from one instance but not the other instances. If that was not what you were implying my bad, sorry.

Comment: @Drag0nvil it's all good man. I've reworded the original post so if you refresh it should be a lot more clear. I've removed all the stuff about static fields.. lol I shouldn't have mixed two questions into one. My bad o.O